# $.inArray on JSON response from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to check `$.inArray` on received data from a ajax call. but doesn't matter how i check it - While the script run, it is always `-1`.

Updated: First declared `shm_kupa` as array (`shm_kupa = [];`)

```
success: function(data) {
    $('ul').html('');
    $.each(data, function(i, value){
        if ($.inArray(data[i].ID, shm_kupa) == -1){
           $('ul').append('<li class="' + data[i].SHM_KUPA + '" data-kupa-id="' + data[i].ID + '">' + data[i].SHM_KUPA + '</li>')
         }
         console.log($.inArray(data[i].ID,shm_kupa)); - Output: -1
         console.log('ID: ' + data[i].ID + ' shm_kupa: ' + shm_kupa); - Output: "ID: 132 shm_kupa: 132,170"
    })
}
```

When i did `console.log`, it showed me `ID: 132 shm_kupa: 132,170`, so the problem probably not with `shm_kupa` as it is declared successfully.

I couldn't find any answer for this problem.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, but `parseInt()` on the received data fixed my problem.

Answer:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('ul').html('');
    $.each(data, function(i, value){
        if ($.inArray(parseInt(data[i].ID), shm_kupa) == -1){
           $('ul').append('<li class="' + data[i].SHM_KUPA + '" data-kupa-id="' + data[i].ID + '">' + data[i].SHM_KUPA + '</li>')
         }
         //console.log($.inArray(data[i].ID,shm_kupa));
         //console.log('ID: ' + data[i].ID + ' shm_kupa: ' + shm_kupa); -
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[$.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), the first parameter is the `value` (in your case 132) and the second parameter must be an `array` (here "132,170" which is a **string**).

Please replace the `shm_kupa` value by an array like [132,170] and that's works ;)

For example this works

```
var shm_kupa = [132,134];
console.log($.inArray(132,shm_kupa)); // Result 0
```

And this doesn't work

```
var shm_kupa = "132,134";
console.log($.inArray(132,shm_kupa)); // Result -1
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hey, i did created an array first. declared it as "shm_kupa = [];" sorry for not mention it.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. Can you try this `console.log(shm_kupa);` before your `console.log($.inArray(data[i].ID,shm_kupa));` ? please

Comment: console.log(shm_kupa) gives 
 [8723, 2128, 8723, 8723, 2129] and undefined immediately after.
for `$.inArray(8723,shm_kupa)`
it gives 0

but while the script run(page loading) it is not working, i think it because $.inArray treats shm_kupa as string and not as an array.

Comment: Can you provide the script which define the `shm_kupa` values ?